# Are there historical problems of wealth/income inequality causing problems for empires?

Tags: economy

I was talking to a friend who said that empires rose and fell upon wealth/income inequality. He cited the Mongols as reducing wealth inequality and the fall of Rome as increasing the inequality. It seems to be reasonable, but looking this up, I cannot find any sources talking about the connection between empire social health/rise and fall and wealth/income inequality.

Are there any examples of this?

Comment: I'm not understanding the hypothesis here. Inequality in what sense... Material wealth? Inequality within the conquering culture, or between the conjuring culture and its neighbors? Is the idea that inequality leads to conquest, or what? What exactly would count as a good example of what you are looking for?

Comment: @BrianZ Inequality within the empire as a whole, to the best of my understanding The idea was inequality lead to social unrest at the bottom and hedonism at the top, which leads to an unstable empire that will most likely fall.

Comment: I'm not sure the modern concepts of wealth and especially income inequality have much meaning in ancient empires where few people were wage workers. The question would benefit from sources that provide evidence for these assertions in each case.

Comment: @BrianZ That's exactly what I'm looking to find/not find (and thus disprove). I was unable to find information either way.

Comment: Only in the modern era has there been a "middle class" - through most of history wealth was concentrated in the hands of the top 10%.  It is like blaming the fall of the empire on right handedness - sure, every empire where right handed people were the majority, but that  has nothing to do with handedness and everything to do with time.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace So this assertion can be trivially disproven? The idea was in *increase* in the amount of inequality - hence the focus on relative inequality rather than absolute inequality.

Comment: Ask your friend to cite his sources to support his assertions. Determining income inequality at a particular point during the Roman Empire is problematic.  Ascertaining change over time even more so.  For an illustration of the complexities involved, see [The Size of the Economy and the Distribution of Income in the Roman Empire](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-roman-studies/article/size-of-the-economy-and-the-distribution-of-income-in-the-roman-empire/ADBB8C20D8DFDB7F5A8B209718AF7942)

Comment: I have no doubt it could be disproven; I question whether it is worth disproving. Your friend is convinced without any evidence.  Such people seldom abandon their convictions when presented with evidence.  China, Rome, Egypt all come to mind as examples of Empires that flourished for generations.  If inequality begins at 90%, who can sense the rise to 91%?

Comment: A statement without proof or argument: how one would argue it pro or contra in a meaningful way? In this way, it sounds much more like ideological statement than historical.

Comment: So the conquerors build rich cities with water piping and central heating for themselves. Their elites become stupendously rich. Provincial population constantly complain about taxes and rebel from time to time. Sound like equality flourished in Empires.

Comment: Historiography rarely if ever accords causative power to single poorly defined sociological or econometric categories. Even complex nuanced textually and diachronically grounded categories like class are heavily contested. The simple answer is “no: historians reject this kind of analysis.”